# Windows Update and lsass.exe

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

I have a brand new installation of Windows XP (SP1 or older). I installed Norton AntiVirus, Firefox, Putty, and Cygwin. No other software is present.

Windows Update finds the following 64 updates: KB905760, KB978262, Internet Explorer 8, KB71961, KB954155, KB968816, KB923561, KB950762, KB949402, KB950974, KB951376, KB951748, KB952004, KB952954, KB955069, KB956572, KB956802, KB956803, KB956844, KB958470, KB958869, KB959426, KB960803, KB960859, KB961501, KB969059, KB970238, KB970238, KB971032, KB971468, KB971657, KB972270, KB973507, KB973815, KB973904, KB974112, KB974318, KB974392, KB975025, KB975560, KB975561, KB975713, .......)

When these updates are applied, the system reboots to a black screen with two error messages. The first error message says:

```
lsass.exe - Application Error

The application failed to initialize properly (0xc00000142). Click on OK to terminate the application.
```

The second error message says:

```
services.exe - Application Error

The application failed to initialize properly (0xc00000142). Click on OK to terminate the application.
```

I then proceed to boot into Safe Mode, use System Restore, and everything works fine again until the 64 updates re-appear in Windows Update. I can see two options: disable Auto-Updates or install each of the 64 updates one at a time until finding the troublesome update.

Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/56998/how-solve-lsass-exe-application-error-on-windows-xp-on-start-up - though not an exact duplicate

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend downloading a copy of SP3 ([from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5b33b5a8-5e76-401f-be08-1e1555d4f3d4&displaylang=en)) and then install that before hooking the computer up to the internet and trying to get online.

This will install all the updates from SP1 and SP2 as well. Windows update will want to install a load of stuff after this, but far less than if you start with SP1.

I did this on my recent rebuild and didn't have any problems.

Comment: SP3 is available from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5b33b5a8-5e76-401f-be08-1e1555d4f3d4&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading the service packs directly and installing them manually? [SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=049c9dbe-3b8e-4f30-8245-9e368d3cdb5a&displaylang=en) [SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5b33b5a8-5e76-401f-be08-1e1555d4f3d4&displaylang=en)

A lot of newer versions of software are not compatible with XP that is at a pre-SP2 patch level. I would check on the compatibility of your version of Norton as well.